# How do I put get the dir of $object[""0""].projhours without syntax err. AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to this, but I need to get the projhours value from this directory in the console.log() without syntax error. on the chrome console when I right click on the directory of projhours I get this ( `$object[""0""].projhours`) but AngularJS clearly doesnt accept `[""0""]`, so how do I get ONLY the projhours value to show on console.log()? (its suppose to be 41222)

the code attached below is when I type `console.log()` for the variable that has the `getlist`.

```
var test = Restangular.allUrl('category/categoryNonProductiveTasks')
            .getList({weekFrom: vm.weekStart.slice(0, 2), weekTo: vm.weekEnd.slice(0, 2), year: vm.selectedYear})
          console.log(test)



Promise {$$state: {…}, call: ƒ, get: ƒ, restangularCollection: true, push: ƒ, …}
$$state: {status: 1, value: Array(1)}
$object: Array(1)
0:
addRestangularMethod: ƒ addRestangularMethodFunction(name, operation, path, defaultParams, defaultHeaders, defaultElem)
all: ƒ all(parent, route)
allUrl: ƒ allUrl(parent, route, url)
clone: ƒ copyRestangularizedElement(element)
customDELETE: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
customGET: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
customGETLIST: ƒ fetchFunction(what, reqParams, headers)
customOperation: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
customPATCH: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
customPOST: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
customPUT: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
doDELETE: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
doGET: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
doGETLIST: ƒ fetchFunction(what, reqParams, headers)
doPATCH: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
doPOST: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
doPUT: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
fromServer: true
get: ƒ getFunction(params, headers)
getList: ƒ fetchFunction(what, reqParams, headers)
getParentList: ƒ ()
getRequestedUrl: ƒ (current, what)
getRestangularUrl: ƒ (current, what)
head: ƒ headFunction(params, headers)
one: ƒ one(parent, route, id, singleOne)
oneUrl: ƒ oneUrl(parent, route, url)
options: ƒ optionsFunction(params, headers)
parentResource: null
patch: ƒ patchFunction(elem, params, headers)
plain: ƒ stripRestangular(elem)
post: ƒ postFunction(what, elem, params, headers)
project: []
projhours: 41222
put: ƒ putFunction(params, headers)
remove: ƒ deleteFunction(params, headers)
reqParams: null
restangularCollection: false
restangularized: true
route: "category/categoryNonProductiveTasks"
save: ƒ save(params, headers)
several: ƒ several(parent, route /*, ids */ )
trace: ƒ traceFunction(params, headers)
withHttpConfig: ƒ withHttpConfig(httpConfig)
yearofdate: 2018
__proto__: Object
addRestangularMethod: ƒ addRestangularMethodFunction(name, operation, path, defaultParams, defaultHeaders, defaultElem)
all: ƒ all(parent, route)
allUrl: ƒ allUrl(parent, route, url)
clone: ƒ copyRestangularizedElement(element)
customDELETE: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
customGET: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
customGETLIST: ƒ fetchFunction(what, reqParams, headers)
customOperation: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
customPATCH: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
customPOST: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
customPUT: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
doDELETE: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
doGET: ƒ customFunction(operation, path, params, headers, elem)
doGETLIST: ƒ fetchFunction(what, reqParams, headers)
doPATCH: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
doPOST: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
doPUT: ƒ (operation, elem, path, params, headers)
fromServer: true
get: ƒ getById(id, reqParams, headers)
getList: ƒ fetchFunction(what, reqParams, headers)
getRequestedUrl: ƒ (current, what)
getRestangularUrl: ƒ (current, what)
head: ƒ headFunction(params, headers)
one: ƒ one(parent, route, id, singleOne)
oneUrl: ƒ oneUrl(parent, route, url)
options: ƒ optionsFunction(params, headers)
parentResource: null
patch: ƒ patchFunction(elem, params, headers)
plain: ƒ stripRestangular(elem)
post: ƒ postFunction(what, elem, params, headers)
putElement: ƒ putElementFunction(idx, params, headers)
remove: ƒ deleteFunction(params, headers)
reqParams: {weekFrom: "1 ", weekTo: "52", year: 2018}
restangularCollection: true
restangularized: true
route: "category/categoryNonProductiveTasks"
several: ƒ several(parent, route /*, ids */ )
trace: ƒ traceFunction(params, headers)
withHttpConfig: ƒ withHttpConfig(httpConfig)
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
call: ƒ promiseCall(method)
get: ƒ promiseGet(what)
push: ƒ promiseCall(method)
restangularCollection: true
__proto__: Object
```

Comment: Are you sure `0` is enclosed with two double quotes? Maybe it's `"0"` and not `""0""`? If it happens that your key contains double quotes, then use single quotes to enclose it `'"0"'`

Comment: @Justinas Nope, i did console.log(test.$object['"0"']) and it got undefined. I also tried console.log(test.$object['"0"]) with the same results

Comment: Can you show us `console.log(test.$object)`?

Comment: @Justinas [test.$object](https://pastebin.com/iuiMq3Se) I uploaded on pastebin due to comment limits, the projhours seems to be in 0:                    [Inside the 0](https://pastebin.com/4RVkZx6h)

Comment: So from your dump it should be simply `test.$object[0].projhours`

Comment: I tried that, it doesnt work(TypeError), but does it being a "promise" effect it?                          `TypeError: Cannot read property 'projhours' of undefined
    at resourceUtilizationByCategory.js:98
    at processQueue (angular.js:16696)
    at angular.js:16712
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17994)
    at Scope.$digest (angular.js:17808)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:18102)
    at done (angular.js:12082)
    at completeRequest (angular.js:12291)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (angular.js:12219)`                               js:98 is cnsle.lg(test.$object[0].projhours)

Comment: @Justinas, sorry i forgotten to tag, pls refer to the message above

Comment: Oh, your `test` is promise, so yes, you should do your logging inside `.then()` function, not outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `test` is Promise, so it does not contain any of your output. You can only access response when your Promise is resolved:

```
Restangular
    .allUrl('category/categoryNonProductiveTasks')
    .getList({
        weekFrom: vm.weekStart.slice(0, 2),
        weekTo: vm.weekEnd.slice(0, 2),
        year: vm.selectedYear
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response, response[0].projhours)
    })
```